# What is the storage quota impact of sending files in Google Chat?

Tags: google-drive, google-workspace-for-business, google-chat

Google provides quite comprehensive [documentation](https://support.google.com/chat/answer/7651457) about how to send files in Google Chat messages, but I have been unable to find any information about how such files affect the sender's Google Drive storage quota.

Of course, none of the files I've attached to chat messages (images or video clips pasted into the text box on Chat's desktop site) in my organization's Workspace account show up in Drive's [quota viewer](https://drive.google.com/drive/quota)—but neither does my email, so it's clear that that tool doesn't show everything. But there's also no category for Chat in the details shown in the Google Workspace view for Drive storage (e.g. `https://drive.google.com/u/1/settings/storage`).

I'm a bit wary of continuing to send files in Chat without knowing their impact on my storage quota. Additional information—whether a direct answer or a pointer to documentation I haven't managed to find on my own—would be much appreciated!

Comment: Supposedly they don't count:
"photos and other files you upload in Google Chat do not count towards your Google account storage quota" from July 12, 2021
https://support.google.com/hangouts/thread/116956267/what-kind-of-things-count-against-my-storage-if-i-m-using-google-chat-with-personal-google-account?hl=en

Comment: @Patrick I'd mark that as the accepted answer if you posted it as one. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**They don't count**, according to a 'volunteer product expert' posting this answer on July 12, 2021:

> photos and other files you upload in Google Chat do not count towards your Google account storage quota.

https://support.google.com/hangouts/thread/116956267/what-kind-of-things-count-against-my-storage-if-i-m-using-google-chat-with-personal-google-account?hl=en

My personal experience seems to confirm this - I've been sending daily images for months, and haven't noticed any affect on my quota.

Answer (score 0):

When "sending a file" from Google Drive on Google Chat you are actually sending a link, so there isn't any impact on the sender's storage quota.

Comment: Not a file from Drive. Google Chat allows uploading or pasting images/videos (for example) directly into the chat box. I've amended the question to clarify.